# JSP servlet connection unsuccessful

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlet-3.0

I am trying to create a simple login and register system using jsp and servlet. This does not giving me any error but the console is displaying connection unsuccessful the jar files are also added.

console msg

```
    Connection unsuccessful
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

login.jsp

```
<form action="sign" method="post" >
        Enter User name : <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
        Enter Password : <input type="text" name="pass"><br> <input
            type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"> <a href = "signin.jsp">Register</a>
    </form>
```

signin.jsp

```
<form action="sign"  method="post">
        Enter User name : <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
        Enter Email : <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Enter Password : <input type="text" name="pass"><br>
        Enter Confirm Password : <input type="text" name="pass2"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Signup">
    </form>
```

Impl.java

```
public User getUser(String username, String paswword) {

        User u = new User();

        try {

            con = c.connect();

            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from signin where uname=? and pass=?");
            ps.setString(1, username);
            ps.setString(2, paswword);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                u.setUsername(rs.getString(1));
                u.setPassword(rs.getString(2));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return u;
    }
```

config.java

```
public Connection connect() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsp", "root", "");

            System.out.println("Connection Successful");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection unsuccessful");
            System.out.println("" + e);
        }

        return con;
    }
```

The only error i am getting is this and the insert command is not executing do i need to add ant dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to add mysql-connector jar inside your lib folder...

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.49/mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar

Copy the above file into your lib directory and restart the server...

Comment: The connection is working now Thank You but the register and login parts are not working still it is not inserting or retriving

Comment: you will need to elaborate "not working".. paste the exception that you are getting.. improve your debugging skills....
also please mark this as the answer and upvote it if it solved your problem...

Comment: The program is working correctly now i have miss the execute command in the servlet and i am sorry that i don't have the enough reputation to upvote the answer but i have mark this as the answer.